# How do I extract and display an element of a web page currently being viewed in the browser

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

So I'm a newbie to programming. I'm currently trying to create a chrome extension.

**How would I extract HTML elements of any web page I'm on and display it in the chrome extension pop up tab?
**

For example, I want to display the meta title of the current page I'm on and display it in the html  file. And whatever page I land on, the function would update to display that specific meta title.

I've tried this piece of code but it of course would not extract the elements from the page I'm browsing but instead my html file.

```
const allElements = document.documentElement;

const metaDescription = document.metaDescription;

if (metaDescription > 170) {
  console.log("Too long");
} else if (metaDescription < 60) console.log("too short");
if (!metaDescription) console.log("doesn't exist");
else console.log("optimised");
```

What would the code be in order to extract the element from the web page the browser is on?

Any help would be much appreciated :)